# How do I check what distribution of CentOS 7 I have installed? (Minimal or Everything)

Tags: centos

So I have CentOS running in a virtual box on my machine, and I downloaded the ISO from [here](https://www.centos.org/download/). Problem is, I can't remember which distribution I used, the Everything ISO or the Minimal ISO. What is a good way to check for that in the Command Line Interface?

Comment: Your Linux distribution is CentOS. You can download bigger (everything) or smaller (minimal) ISO. They differ by number of packages written in image. So installing from bigger image will probably result in less data downloaded from Internet. IMHO, those days it matter only in certain scenarios, where you don't have access to decent Internet connection on installation box. Note, that after installation in both cases you have access to same repositories (set of packages).

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to check out what you initially installed, check the `%packages` section of `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg`

If you did a minimum install, it should look like:

```
@minimal
@core
```

If you installed from the Everything ISO and, for exmaple, specified a graphical server install, it should look like:

```
@graphical-server-environment
@base
@core
@desktop-debugging
@dial-up
@fonts
@gnome-desktop
@guest-agents
@guest-desktop-agents 
@input-methods
@internet-browser
@multimedia
@print-client
@x11
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is

```
rpm --query centos-release
```

or

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

or

```
hostnamectl
```

as described in detail at https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-your-centos-version/#alternative-methods-to-check-centos-version

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release` not give the OS minor version. Should I do something more?

Answer (score 1):

It’s all about size of ISO image and amount preinstalled packages, the CentOS base is the same. Because of this, I think, that checking from which ISO image you have installed your current system is unnecessary, but it may be possible indirectly, by checking which packages were installed additionally by package manager (only my assumption).

I don’t use CentOS, but use Ubuntu full version and minimal version - difference are following: minimal version doesn’t have GUI and packages like Firefox, Libreoffice, etc. Only base/minimal working system with command line interface only. If I want add packages - I install them manually by package manager from same repositories. In full version they all preinstalled and configured. In the end I can transform minimal to full version, by installing all needed packages.

Here is a brief explanation about Centos 7 ISO images differences http://centos.ufes.br/7/isos/x86_64/0_README.txt

> **CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1611.iso**
>   This DVD image contains all the
>   packages that can be installed using the   installer. This is the
>   recommended image for most users.
>
> **CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso**
>   This image contains the complete
>   set of packages for CentOS 7. It can be    used for installing or
>   populating a local mirror. This image needs a dual    layer DVD or an
>   8GB USB flash drive.
>
> **CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso**
>   The aim of this image is to install
>   a very basic CentOS 7 system, with the minimum of packages needed to
>   have a functional system. Please burn this image onto a CD and boot
>   your computer off it. A preselected set of packages will be installed
>   on your system. Everything else needs to be installed using yum. The
>   set of packages installed by this image is identical to the one
>   installed when choosing the group named "Minimal" from the full DVD
>   image.